# c# and WPF texbox word selection between specified characters

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a very tricky question for you guys.

Lets say i have a Textbox that I've created in WPF

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="465" Width="681">
    <Grid>
       <TextBox x:Name="textbox1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As far as i know a Textbox holds the values in it as a string.

Now i enter some text into the Textbox such as `Hello World! It is a %great% day!`

note that great is surrounded by percentages, when this happens and the user scrolls over that word it becomes highlighted so that the user cannot edit that specific word, making it sort of a variable. How would i go about this?

The reason im asking this weird question is because i have a listbox that i can drag items from and drop them into my textbox, but i dont want the user to drop a variable inside of another nor can they put text between the variable, it must either replace it or deleted it if selected and the user starts typing.

Here is my sample code, can you tell me if i am on the right track.

`C#`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listbox1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listbox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListBoxItem mySelectedItem = listbox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
            if (mySelectedItem != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listbox1, "%" + mySelectedItem.Content.ToString()+"%", DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }                
        }
    }

    private void textbox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void textbox1_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DragEventArgs p;
        p = e;
        Point curpos = p.GetPosition(textbox1);
        int pos1;
        pos1 = textbox1.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(curpos, true) + 1;
        label1.Content = pos1.ToString();

        string TEXT = textbox1.Text;

        if(!textbox1.Text.Length.Equals(0))
        {
            string sLeft = TEXT.Substring(0, pos1);
            string sRight = TEXT.Substring(pos1, TEXT.Length - pos1);
            string sText = "";
            int end, length;

            //instrev funct

            if(sLeft.Contains("%"))
            {
                end = sRight.IndexOf("%") +pos1;
                length = end - pos1+2;
                textbox1.SelectionStart = pos1-1;
                textbox1.SelectionLength = length;
            }
        }

    }

    private void textbox1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string tstring;
        tstring = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
    }

    private void textbox1_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point curpos = e.GetPosition(textbox1);
        int pos1;
       pos1 = textbox1.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(curpos, true) + 1;
        label1.Content = pos1.ToString();
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Idea**
As soon as you release the ListBoxItem on top of the TextBox, you can get the coordinates of the mouse event. With these, you can try to find the word by counting the letters which fit in between the start and the mouse event. Knowing the word, you can then alter the *TextBox.Text* accordingly by replacing the old substring with the new one.

**Conclusion** I do not think that this approach is particularly robust as it depends on the width of the characters, but it should at least work. Looking at the WPF TextBox API, there is no high-level support for your endeavour.

**Resource**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx

Comment: As mentioned it is a tricky question and i don't expect there to be much support, but if I'm not mistaken selecting the left and right of the sub-string should make it work.